# Molecular orbital normalization

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, molecular-dynamics

Suppose that a molecular orbital has the format (not normalized) `0.145A+ 0.844B` **(1)**. How do I find a linear combination between `A` and `B`, with `A` and `B` being orthonormal eigenstates, that is ortogonal to **(1)**? 
And about the normalization constants, using the superposition integral equals to **S = 0.250**?

I know the answer to this problem is `N(0.844A-0.145B)`, but i don't know how to get there.

Comment: Welcome to SE!  Are $A$ and $B$ orthonormal eigenstates?  What does $S=0.250$ mean?  It would be helpful if you could define your variables/functions.

Comment: @Will Sorry, I just updated my question!

Comment: no problem; Julius beat me to the answer anyway ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this can help you get started: in general, if some wave function is given by a superposition of orthogonal states, e.g.:

$$|\psi\rangle = a|1\rangle + b |2\rangle,$$

any wave function $|\phi\rangle \equiv c|1\rangle + d|2\rangle$ orthogonal to it must satisfy $\langle\phi|\psi\rangle$ = 0. We can expand the bra-ket, and then find:

$$c^*a + d^*b = 0.$$

Depending on whether you require $|\phi\rangle$ to be normalized or not this equation has one or infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Umm, thank you very much, you helped me a lot. But I still don't know how to get the normalization constants, can you give some hints?

Comment: This is a relation that the coefficients $a,b,c,d$ must satisfy in order for the two states to be orthogonal. If you don't care about normalization, this is the only requirement, meaning we can choose any value for $c$ we want, and $d$ will follow (or the other way around). Assuming everything is real, we can set $c = b$, then it directly follows that $d = -a$.